# custom ITemplate in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemplate

So.

I have a custom dropdownlist:

```
public class LabelTemplate : ITemplate
{

    string __field;

    public LabelTemplate(string _field)
    {
        __field = _field;
    }

    private void Combo_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label l = (Label)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)l.NamingContainer;
        l.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, __field ).ToString();
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        Label _l = new Label();
        _l.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.Combo_DataBinding);
        container.Controls.Add(_l);
    }

}


public class ListTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public ListTemplate(string _field, string _query, WebLogic _transport)
    {
        _vfield = _field;
        _vquery = _query;
        _vtransport=_transport;
    }


    protected WebLogic _vtransport;
    protected string _vfield;
    protected string _vquery;
    protected DataRow _vrow;

    private void Combo_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList l = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)l.NamingContainer;
        l.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "SowingID").ToString();
    }



    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {

        DropDownList _l = new DropDownList();
        try
        {
            DataTable _z = _vtransport.GetList(_vquery);
            foreach (DataRow _r in _z.Rows)
            {
                ListItem _ll = new ListItem(_r[1].ToString(), _r[0].ToString());
                _l.Items.Add(_ll);
            }
        }
        catch {
            _l.Items.Add(new ListItem("Error", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
        }
        _l.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.Combo_DataBinding);


        container.Controls.Add(_l);
    }
}



public partial class edtRegistry : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            TemplateField _fld = new TemplateField();
            //Label
            LabelTemplate _lab = new LabelTemplate("SowingID"); 
            // DropDownList
            ListTemplate _lal = new ListTemplate(_cc.ColumnName, _reg._vrfqueries    [_reg._valuefields.IndexOf(_cc.ColumnName)], Transport); 

           _fld.HeaderText = _cc.ColumnName;
            _fld.ItemTemplate = _lab; 
            _fld.EditItemTemplate = _lal; 

            GridView1.Columns.Add(_fld);
        }
    }
}
```

And so on. The GridView1 has autogenerated "Edit" button, so when I click it, I'm having an error - "The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled".

How can I avoid this error and just Edit the data?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using AutoGenerateEditButton="True" in your grid?

Comment: If yes then make it false like AutoGenerateEditButton="false".

Comment: Yes, it is "True" there, but... should I use my own coded Edit button, right? I like autoedit buttons.

Comment: If you are using autoedit then handle it's event.

Comment: Otherwise just make it false.

Comment: Okay. Excuse me, how should I "handle" it in this case?

Comment: I mean, does _fld.EditItemTemplate = _lal; do it by itself?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Make `AutoGenerateEditButton = false`

**Solution 2:**

If you want to use AutoEdit button then handle the events like:

in aspx page, in your grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
```

and in Code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //Your code here
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   // Write here code for edit Rows 
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, but what exactly should I place there, in RowEditing code?

Comment: Code to edit your record. If there is none then leave it empty.